# Запятая перед или. (Либо)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, или

Уникально(,) или никак.

[предложение в смысле "либо уникально, либо никак"]

Если запятая присутствует, уточните, почему.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без запятой: это однородные члены предложения, соединенные неповторяющимся разделительным союзом "или".

Answer (score 0):

Кстати говоря, запятая перед **зачем** в предложении *Если запятая присутствует, уточните, почему* не нужна. Что касается темы вопросы, то ответ вам выше уже дали, причём он правильный.